# I have an object it contains array with object. How can I implement this transformation?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

## Input

```
{
    "address": [{
        "extraId": "AB",
        "globe": "0980098",
        "newAddress": [{
            "name": "addressName",
            "value": "XY,0980980980"
        }]
    }],
    "products": [{
            "productName": "ACC"
        },
        {
            "productName": "SSSS"
        },
        {
            "productName": "DDDD"
        },
        {
            "productName": "FFF"
        }
    ],
    "additionaldata": [{
        "name": "asasa",
        "value": "23232"
    }]
}
```

## output

```
{
    "extraId": "AB",
    "globe": "0980098",
    "newAddress": [{
        "name": "addressName",
        "value": "XY,0980980980"
    }],
    "products": [{
            "productName": "ACC"
        },
        {
            "productName": "SSSS"
        },
        {
            "productName": "DDDD"
        },
        {
            "productName": "FFF"
        }
    ],
    "additionaldata": [{
        "name": "asasa",
        "value": "23232"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var address = payload.address[0]
---
address ++ (payload - "address")
```